# Regularity of Kantorovich potentials

Tags: optimal-transport

I'm looking for a reference of a result in Optimal Transport. I know that if $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $c\in C^1$ (the transportation cost), then $c$ is Lipschitz continuous on $\Omega\times\Omega$ and hence all the Kantorovich potentials, which are $c$-concave, are Lipschitz as well, and then differentiable a.e. May you suggest me a reference (book/article) for such a (combination of) result(s)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is given in ["Lectures on Optimal Transport"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-72162-6) by Ambrosio, Brué and Semola.

[image]

[image]